# Can camel generate File from java object

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, filewriter

I need to generate a large file which is going to be done in Java, so a method is hit and the service goes off to the repository returns a list of type X as Java object. I then need to place this list in a file and send this off to an ftp server.

I know I can put files on ftp servers using camel, but wanted to know if it possible for camel to generate the file from the Java object and then place on the ftp server?

My code would look like this:

```
 List<ObjectX> xList = someRepo.getListOfx();
```

So I need to write xList to a file and place on the ftp server.

Comment: What we can get from a small code snapshot?

Comment: It will be hard to answer if you don't tell us what kind of format you want to use in the file: is it XML? JSON? CSV? Some binary format (for example from Java serialization)? Also, what have you already tried?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part out, file would be csv. Well I know I can just create the file using a FileWriter in java but thought it would be nice to let camel do all the work. Currently working on file producer to find a way.

Comment: There is a cvs-componet! --> [Camel-CSV](http://camel.apache.org/csv.html) You only need a List<Map> insted of a List<ObjectX>

Comment: Thanks for the reply unfortunately I need to use my domain object. I'm going to try and implement using bindy mentioned @Cyäegha reply.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, to convert your POJO messages to/from a text (or binary) based representation, you can use a [Camel Dataformat](http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html). In your route, you will use the `marshall` and `unmarshall` keywords to perform the conversion.

There are several Camel dataformats available to marshall/unmarshal CSV, including the [CSV dataformat](http://camel.apache.org/csv.html) or the [Bindy dataformat](http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html) (but there are a few others listed on the Dataformat page, under the "Flat data structure marshalling" header). One advantage of Bindy is that it can also support other unstructured formats (such as fixed width records)

Also note :

- With Bindy, you will have to add annotations to your model class (`ObjectX`)
- With CSV, you will have to convert you model objects (of type `ObjectX`) to `Map`s (or register an appropriate `TypeConverter` with Camel to do this conversion automatically)
- If you check the other available dataformats, they may have different requirements too

Here is a very simple example with bindy:

```
package mypackage;

@CsvRecord(separator = ",")
public Class MyPojo {
    @DataField(pos = 1) // first column in the CSV file
    private int foo;
    @DataField(pos = 2) // second column in the CSV file
    private String bar;
    // Plus constructors, accessors, etc.
}

// In the RouteBuilder :
DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat("mypackage");

from("...") // Message received as a List<MyPojo>
    .marshal(bindy)
    .to("ftp:...");
```

Comment: Bindy sounds like the solution for me, currently trying to set this up. Thanks